# Source? The day you were born was the day Gd decided the universe could no longer exist without you

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

I am looking for the source for the following quote

> The day you were born was the day Gd decided the universe could no longer exist without you

The greeting card I saw it on said the quote was from the Talmud.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, it's attributed to Rabbi Nahman of Breslov:

http://ancienthebrewpoetry.typepad.com/ancient_hebrew_poetry/2009/11/rabbi-nachman-of-breslov-on-election-and-responsibility.html

The Hebrew, from there, is:
היום בו נולדת הוא היום בו החליט הקב''ה שהעולם אינו יכול להתקיים בלעדיך.

But unfortunately even with the original Hebrew I can't find an actual source for it in his writings.

Comment: It is Rebbe Nachman of Breslev zy'a, from an oral tradition.  I'll try to find if it's written somewhere.  It is most likely in connection with Likutey Moharan I 5, which is based on the Mishnah @AvrohomYitzchok brings below.

Comment: @yoel I actually have it on good authority (my own "oral tradition" from R' Kramer, I suppose) that Rabbeinu za"l (Rebbe Nachman) never said that. I have never seen it in any of the seforim. A quick search of Sefaria also revealed no source, although Sefaria is hardly exhaustive.

Answer (score 3):

I think the source is, expressed slightly differently 
[towards the end of Mishnah Sanhedrin 4:5 where it says,](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/h/h44.htm)

> לפיכך לכל אחד ואחד לומר, בשבילי נברא העולם

“Therefore everyone must say, ‘For my sake, the world was created.’ ”

Answer (score -2):

The source is from The Lubavitcher Rebbe spoken on several occasions in 1988.  The Rebbe instituted the idea of celebrating birthdays with hachlotas tovos giving extra tzedoka, making a birthday celebration and several other directives to inspire oneself spiritualy on their birthday and to carry that inspiration all year.

Comment: please quote where is it written in Lubavitcher Rebbe books

Comment: Other answers already source this to decades before 1988, so this is wrong.

Comment: @DoubleAA There's been no primary source cited to the other direct answer, and I've actually heard from a scholar that the commonly-assumed source is incorrectly cited. It's entirely possible that it actually was the Lubavitcher Rebbe, but a source here would be nice.