# Rebbe Nachman of Breslov - "science tells you how, Torah tells you why". Anyone have a source for this?

Tags: sources-mekorot, hashkafah-philosophy, torah-study, science, breslov

Heard here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gag_myt1hWw

Is this quotation correct? If so, where is the source? Thank you.

Comment: It's a very common quote, if you substitute "religion" for "Torah".

Comment: In my experience, people commonly attribute phrases and aphorisms to Rebbe Nachman that he never said, just because they sound good. E.g. "the day you were born is the day Hashem decided that the world couldn't exist without you" or something similar - I have it on good authority from a Breslover mashpia that there is no legitimate source from Rebbe Nachman where he says that.

Comment: @Yehuda see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27550/source-the-day-you-were-born-was-the-day-gd-decided-the-universe-could-no-longe, might be Oral Tradition, or even earlier than Rebbe Nachman.

Comment: @Yehuda, that quote about the day you were born was from R Kook, with toe in to עד שנולדתי איני כדאי...  From Vidui. It is a real thought, but a misattribution. Like the way many Mussarists' thoughts are said in the name of the Chafeitz Chaim or if the speaker leans more Chassidic - R Zushia.

Comment: R Lord Jonathan Sacks zt"l used the line in this question a lot.

Comment: @MichaBerger thanks and thanks for your answer to my other question. I am still osek in it. By the way, what you just said would make a good answer for the linked question